# How to use scrapy with django and upload it to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape some data. But I want to use it with django for user interface and to save the data to database. Also I want to know how can I upload it to heroku

Comment: Nice, but where is the question?

Comment: Do you want know method or you want whole code? You may like to refer https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/how-to-use-scrapy-with-django-application-c16fabd0e62e  article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you can look into is this django project which has scrapy embedded in it. You will have to figure out the part of deploying this to heroku.

https://github.com/bipul21/scrapy_django
http://bipuljain.com/blog/using-scrapy-with-django-14